# Checking if song is present in user's Spotify library

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, spotify

Using the below code to check if the user's library contains a particular song. It returns an error. What could I be doing wrong? I couldn't find examples for this particular 'forCheckingIfSavedTracksContains' method anywhere.

```
let accessToken = SPTAuth.defaultInstance().sessionUserDefaultsKey
let request: URLRequest = try! 
SPTYourMusic.createRequest(forCheckingIfSavedTracksContains: ["spotify:track:3ZakaL0QEt5eeD3N7HbaN1"], forUserWithAccessToken: accessToken)
SPTRequest.sharedHandler().perform(request) { (error, response, data) in
    if error == nil {
        print ("this is data\(String(describing: data))")
    } else {
        print ("error")
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks/contains?ids=, NSUnderlyingError=0x109e7eb60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey=<CFURLResponse 0x109e7e970 [0x1b441e538]>{url = api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks/contains?ids=}}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks/contains?ids=}

Comment: you don't have a valid token. The code you have simply gets a  string that is used to save the session in user defaults.

Comment: SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.accessToken is this supposed to be the user token? how do I get/save my user token?

Comment: When I try to access that value I get unexpectedly found nil

Comment: Okay I figured it out I wasn't using the right session object. Thanks @Paulw11! I get the data now, but it looks like this when I print it out 'Optional(85 bytes)' I thought it was supposed to be a Bool value, the documentation doesn't say, does anyone know ?